# Next JS: SSG not working in when passed as prop for a component in production mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am currently working on a project of mine, where SSG doesn't work when data is passed as props to child components from the page components. It is pretty difficult to recreate the issue so I'll try my best to explain it rather.

So I have a folder structure somewhat like this:

```
└── pages/
    ├── home/
    │   ├── _slider.tsx
    │   └── more .tsx files
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── _app.tsx
    └── _doucment.tsx
```

The `index.tsx` is a page whereas `_slider.tsx` is a component that is imported by `index.tsx`.
The content of `index.tsx` is similar to the one below:

```
const Home: React.FC<{ sliderData: IsliderData[] }> = (props) => {
  //Refs

  const homeRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="home" ref={homeRef}>
      <Nav className="home-nav" ref={homeRef} />
      <Slider data={props.sliderData} />
     
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
 //Fetches data and returns the data as sliderData

  return {
    props: {
      sliderData,
    },
  };
};
```

The content of `_slider.tsx` is similar to the one below:

```
const Slider: React.FC<{ data: IsliderData[] }> = ({ data }) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="slider">
            {data.map((card, index) => (
             <div>The data is used here</div>
            ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, all these work fine on the development server but as soon as I try to build the app I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and this error is pointing the the line that has the `data.map` in `_slider.tsx`

Any ways to fix the issue?

I think that the fetched data is not being properly passed as a props to the child component when building out the production version. Just my assumption.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition to separating your components from the `pages/` folder like mentioned in @Danila's answer, make sure you check that `props.sliderData` is not undefined when rendering the `Slider` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every file inside `pages` directory is a page (except for `_app` and `_document`), and when you build your app NextJs is going to build `/home/_slider.html` too (even if you mark it with dash it does not matter for Next), but it can't do that because you are not providing `data` prop for it.

If you want to use some component, but don't want it to become a page, you need to place it somewhere else outside of `/pages`, for example `/components` directory and import it from there:

```
└── components/
    ├── slider.tsx
└── pages/
    ├── home.tsx
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── _app.tsx
    └── _doucment.tsx
```